# set up two factor authentication with Google but only if a public key is not used

Tags: ssh, authentication

I have key setup from host1 to host2 and host2 to host1 for SSH. I want to setup two factor authentication with Google on host1 and host2 but only if the incoming connection is from another place. So, if there is no public key provided only then should it try two factor? Any ideas?

Comment: If they have the same ssh key on both hosts, it bypasses the Google Authenticator.  Without the key, it asks for Authorization Code.  I just set this up and tried with remote and local access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that there are location/user specific options that can be specified in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.  Take a look at the man page.

Also I believe that you could make modifications to the pam.d authorizations to accomodate what you wish as well.  I'm not much of an expert in pam modules however but that is definitely another choice.